# Getting prepare Hook error while trying to run test cases using appium

Tags: appium, wdio

2022-06-20T10:22:26.412Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook

2022-06-20T10:23:22.099Z ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook

Error: Appium exited before timeout (exit code: 1)

```
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Joyi\Downloads\webdriverio-appium-course-master\webdriverio-appium-course-master\node_modules\@wdio\appium-service\build\launcher.js:110:22)

at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)

at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)

at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:475:12)

at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
```